# Call two functions when onsubmit

Tags: javascript

Basically I have three functions (Format(), checkEmpty() and validDate()). One makes sure the format is correct the second that something has been entered and the third checks that the dates are not in the past etc. (Booking form for a basic airline webpage). I want both functions to be run and if both are valid then move to testpage.py

```
<Form action="testpage.py" method="POST" name="MyForm" onsubmit="return !!(Format() & validDate());">
```

```
function checkEmpty(userdate) {


      if (userdate == '' || userdate == null  ) {
            return false; 
      }
      else
      {
            return true; 
      }
}


function Format() { 

       var departuredate = document.getElementById("departdate").value; 
       var arrivaldate = document.getElementById("arrivedate").value;

       var pattern1 = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;  //dd/mm/yyyy

       var pattern2 = /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/;   //yyyy-mm-dd  for Chrome with date type input field

       var output1a = pattern1.test(departuredate);
       var output1b = pattern2.test(departuredate);

       var output2a = pattern1.test(arrivaldate);
       var output2b = pattern2.test(arrivaldate);


       if(!checkEmpty(departuredate))
       {

            alert("Empty date - Please enter date again in format: dd/mm/yyyy");
            document.getElementById("departdate").focus();
            document.getElementById("departdate").style.border='2px solid red';   
            return false;  

       } 
       else if(!checkEmpty(arrivaldate))
       {
            alert("Empty date - Please enter date again in format: dd/mm/yyyy");
            document.getElementById("arrivedate").focus();
            document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border='2px solid red';
            return false;              
       }
       else
       {

            if (output1a){
                  departdate = departuredate.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3");
                  alert('Dates are validated');
                  return true;
            }
            else if (output1b)
            {
                  departdate = departuredate.replace(/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})/, "$2/$3/$1"); 
                  alert('Dates are validated');
                  return true;
            }
            else
            {
                  alert("Incorrect date format - Please enter the arrival date again in format: dd/mm/yyyy");
                  document.getElementById("departdate").focus();
                  document.getElementById("departdate").style.border='2px solid red';   
                  return false;

            }         


            if (output2a)
            {

                  arrivedate = arrivaldate.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3");
                  alert('Dates are validated');
                  return true;
            }
            else if (output2b)
            {
                  arrivedate = arrivaldate.replace(/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})/, "$2/$3/$1")
                      alert('Dates are validated');
                  return true;          
            }

            else
            {
                  alert("Incorrect date format - Please enter the departure date again in format: dd/mm/yyyy");
                  document.getElementById("arrivedate").focus();
                  document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border='2px solid red';              
                  return false;

            }
      }
} 

function validDate(){

       var months3 = 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //3 months 
       var departuserspecifiedTime = departuredate.getTime();
       var arrivaluserspecifiedTime = arrivaldate.getTime();  
       var currentTime = CurrentDate.getTime(); //current time and date
       var departdifference = departuserspecifiedTime - currentTime; //difference between departure time and the current time
       var arrivaldifference = arrivaluserspecifiedTime - currentTime; //difference between arrival time and the current time

            if (departdifference <= (1000 * 60 * 60)) //if the departure time is in the past or within an hour of the current time, it is invalidated as it is too soon
            {
                document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Date selected is in the past";
                document.MyForm.departdate.focus();
                document.getElementById("departdate").style.border='1px solid red';
                return false;
            }

            if (arrivaldifference <= (1000 * 60 * 60)) //if the arrival time is in the past or within an hour of the current time, it is invalidated as it is too soon
            {
                document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Date selected is in the past";
                document.MyForm.arrivedate.focus();
                document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border='1px solid red';
                return false;
            }


            if (departdifference && arrivaldifference >= months3) //if the departure/arrival date is over 3 months away from todays date it is invalidated
            {
                document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Only 3 months advance booking is allowed";
                document.getElementById("departdate").style.border='1px solid red';
                document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border='1px solid red';
                return false;

            }

            if (arrivaluserspecifiedTime < departuserspecifiedTime) // if the arrival date is before the departure date it is invalidated 
            {
                alert("Arrival date selected is in the past") ;
                document.getElementById("departdate").focus();
                document.getElementById("arrivedate").focus();
                    document.getElementById("departdate").style.border='1px solid red';
                    document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border='1px solid red';
                    return false;

            }

             else 
            {
                // if none of the above situaton's occur then the input is true and validated
                alert('Dates are validated');
                return true;          
            }

}
```

Comment: That's some validation? That can't possibly be a *"Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"*? Also, what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `evt.preventDefault()` [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), so you can avoid the submit event.

```
<Form action="testpage.py" method="POST" name="MyForm" onsubmit="my_validate_function(evt)">
```

and something like this:

```
function validar_campos(evt) {
    var resp;
    resp =  Format();
    if (!resp) {//false
        alert("something goes wrong");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    resp =  validDate();
    if (!resp) {
        alert("something goes wrong");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

You also could use a

```
<button type="button" onclick="my_validate_function()">Click to submit</button>
```

Instead of submit button